# MongoDB C# Driver and Thread Safety

Tags: c#, mongodb, thread-safety, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

In the documentation for `MongoClient`, `MongoServer`, `MongoDatabase` and `MongoCollection<T>` I see that it's said that they are thread-safe.

Question: Does that mean I can have (for example) static fields of them in a class and access them from any `Task`/`Thread`?

Like:

```
public static MongoClient Client = new MongoClient(Properties.Settings.Default.MongoConnStr);
public static MongoServer Server = Client.GetServer();
public static MongoDatabase DraftDB = Server.GetDatabase("draftdb");
public static MongoCollection<MyDoc> Docs = Program.DraftDB.GetCollection<Location>("mydocs");
```

Specially about `MongoCollection<T>`; I want to be sure that something like `var cursor = Docs.Find(query).SetLimit(50);` does not perform a mutation on the `MongoCollection<T>` (It's static state to be precise).

Comment: so yes and no. while normal operations on the fields will not change their "state" for other threads/tasks, you might want to hide (encapsulate) mutating functions in private methods to avoid changing their state by mistake (such as accidentally overwriting or unassigning their value).  Take a look at this code which is C# driver code Unit tests: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/296795e687d62dd97bd38204ccd026644fa76eae/MongoDB.DriverUnitTests/Configuration.cs

Comment: note that MongoCursor class is *not* thread safe, so your example is a good one - getting a cursor back from a collection  - it's safe for the collection field but the cursor returned is of course not thread safe and must not be shared between tasks.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks; But here `MongoCursor` is not used as a shared resource (like a public static field). But I do not know `MongoCollection<MyDoc>` is thread safe, or not, yet, by looking at the linked sample.

Comment: You know MongoCollection is thread-safe from here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#thread-safety

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Thanks; please add it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [this page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/connecting/) you know that MongoServer, MongoDatabase, MongoClient, MongoCollection and MongoGridFS are thread safe.  MongoCursor is specifically *not* thread-safe.

This means you can safely access them from multiple tasks without worrying about that changing their "state" - however you still have to take care around how to set or change their values.

Specifically to your question, querying a collection (which returns a cursor object) does *not* mutate the MongoCollection object.